# TypeError: Super expression must be null or a function, not undefined with Babeljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, babeljs

I'm currently trying to make multiple-files inheritance in ES6, with node.JS and Babel (I'm using Babel to convert the code from ES6 to ES5 'cause Node don't implement ES6 right now).
I'm using import/export to "link" the differents files.

Actually I have :
**Parent Class (File 1)**

```
export class Point
{
    constructor(x, y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    toString() {
        return '(' + this.x + ', ' + this.y + ')';
    }
}
```

And :
**Child Class (File 2)**

```
import Point from './pointES5'

export class ColorPoint extends Point
{
    constructor(x, y, color)
    {
        super(x, y);
        this.color = color;
    }

    toString() {
        return super.toString() + ' in ' + this.color;
    }
}
```

And the main
**Main (File 3)**

```
import Point from './pointES5'
import ColorPoint from './colorpointES5'

var m_point = new Point();
var m_colorpoint = new ColorPoint();

console.log(m_point.toString());
console.log(m_colorpoint.toString());
```

I'm doin' that to test the toString() methods calls, from Parent and from Child.
So then I use Babel to convert the code from ES6 to ES5 and I run each parts separately to test if it's ok or not.
- Point (the Parent) is good, and execute without error.
- ColorPoint (the Child) don't run completely and throw :

> TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

The first line of the StackTrace is :

> function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError('Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.**proto** = superClass; }
>   (It comes from the ES5 converted code (Babelified), and I can post it entirely if it's needed).

It is frustrating cause this code is very simple...
But I don't see what is causing the error.

I try differents versions of Babel (5, 5.8, 6) but there is no differences...

What have I done wrong ?

PS : I forgot to tell : it WORKS PERFECTLY when I do that in just one file. But it's really important to me to have only one class by file...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your export doesn't match your import:

```
export class Point
// and
import Point from './pointES5'
```

You're exporting a named symbol but importing the default, so you'll be getting the wrong object as `Point` in your second file.

You can either use:

```
export default class Point
```

in the first class file or

```
import {Point} from './pointES5';
```

in the second file to fetch the right reference. If you're going for the single-class-per-file layout, I'd suggest the former. You'll typically only have a single class being exported, so it makes sense to have that as the default.

What you have now is the equivalent of:

```
// in Point
module.exports = {
  Point: Point
};

// in ColorPoint
var Point = require('./pointES5'); // will point to *the whole object*

class SubPoint extends Point
```

Comment: Wow damn ! I understand a bit more what the "default" keyword is and for what it is used now ! Thank you so much for your help !
It works perfectly ! :D

Comment: In the case that you are using webpack for bundling, I recommend using the second approach suggested by @ssube which would take advantage of webpack's 2.0 tree shaking for performance purposes: http://2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html

Answer (score 1):

It could also be a problem in your webpack config, if you are using webpack as a bundler.
Or how you uglify your code. for example how I solved my specific issue with the NPM package *react-draft-wysiwyg* and the wepback plugin *uglifyjs-webpack-plugin*.

What worked for me here was to set the **inline** option for the **compress** option to false because by default it is **true** for the **uglifyOptions**.

```
optimization:{
  minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
  uglifyOptions: {
    compress: {
      inline: 1, // this right here
      // keep_fnames: true
    },
    mangle: {
      // keep_fnames: true
    }
  }
})]
}
```